# ASP.NET Core текущий пользователь отображается неавторизированным

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Имеется БД с 2-мя ролями и с 2-мя пользователями под каждую из них. Есть форма для авторизации, метод авторизации выглядит так:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel login)
    {
        if(!@ModelState.IsValid)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(login.Username, login.Password, true, false);

        if(result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(login.Username);
            var isLector = await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "lector");

            if (isLector)
            {
                return View("~/Views/Home/Lector.cshtml", user);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("~/Views/Home/Student.cshtml", user);
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Авторизация проходит успешно, пользователя находит, роль опеределяется без проблем. Проблема возникает дальше: в этом же контроллере есть 2 других метода.

```
    [Authorize(Roles="student")]
    public IActionResult OnlyStudent()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles="lector")]
    public IActionResult OnlyLector()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Так вот когда происходит переход на любой из них, в адресную строку возвращается ссылка следюущего типа: http://localhost:5000/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FOnlyLector
Что говорит о том, что текущий пользователь - User является не авторизированным. Вопрос: как это исправить и почему пользователь который прошел авторизацию в методе Login не подвязывается под текущего пользователя. Извините если сказал глупость, новичек в Asp.Net

Answer (score 0):

```
await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(login.Username, login.Password, true, false);
```

Данный метод выполнял авторизацию правильно, дело было в том что запоминания пользователя как и его роли выполнялось через куки, а у меня в настройках браузера стоял запрет на запоминания куки именно для localhost:5000 (выставил когда-то давно и забыл) из-за чего не происходила запись куки и следовательно уже при следующем обновлении страницы либо же переходе на другой метод наш пользователь уже считался анонимным, из-за чего атрибуты

```
 Authorize
```

И перебрасывали на страницу авторизации.

Comment: Расширьте ответ, сделав его более полным, пожалуйста.